# Can I apply animations to margins?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to animate in CSS3 margins, which [this site](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transitions/) seems to say you can, but I can't get working.

I actually have 3 animations. 1 for a simple initial `fadeIn` on initial load, then the 2 others for the `margin` animation on click. I've also just tried `margin` instead of the top and bottom but still no sign of it working.

Click on a section to see animation toggle.

```js
$(".section").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("open");
});
```

```css
body{
    background: #f1f1f1;
}

.section{
    display: block;
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
    animation: fadeIn .5s ease, margin-top .5s ease, margin-bottom .5s ease;
}
.section.open {
    margin: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="section">Some content</div>
    <div class="section">Some content</div>
    <div class="section">Some content</div>
    <div class="section">Some content</div>
    <div class="section">Some content</div>
    <div class="section">Some content</div>
    <div class="section">Some content</div>
</div>
```

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ybh0thp9/3/

Comment: You need to show **all** the keyframe animations if you expect us to debug them but couldn't you just do this with a transition - http://jsfiddle.net/ybh0thp9/5/

Comment: You seem to be confusing animations and transitions and appear to be trying to fade something in from being invisible after someone clicks on the thing they cannot see.

Comment: oh, yes indeed. I did confuse the animation and transition!

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You don't need keyframes for this: http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/ybh0thp9/7/

```
transition: margin 700ms;
```

You need to add the transition property to the base element that you wish to animate.

You also mentioned that you wanted opacity change, but I don't see how that's possible considering you only have a single element without children. I mean: you can't click on the element if it's hidden.

What you can do, though, is add opacity to the whole thing: http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/ybh0thp9/9/

Or even prettier, with a transformation:

http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/ybh0thp9/10/

```
.section {
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0.7;
    transform: scale(0.85);
    transition: all 700ms;
}
.section.open {
    margin: 20px 0;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

---

Per comment, you want to fade in the elements on page load. We can do that by adding a class `init`.

http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/ybh0thp9/12/

```
$(".section").addClass("init"); // JS
.section.init {opacity: 1;} // CSS
```

---

With keyframes: http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/ybh0thp9/14/

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { from {opacity: 0; } to { opacity: 1; } }
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn { from {opacity: 0; } to { opacity: 1; } }
@keyframes fadeIn { from {opacity: 0; } to { opacity: 1; } }

-webkit-animation: fadeIn 1.5s ease;    
-moz-animation: fadeIn 1.5s ease;
animation: fadeIn 1.5s ease;
```

Comment: Thanks! I added back the animation in CSS for it with the keyframes (prefered over jquery adding a class). And it works!  http://jsfiddle.net/ybh0thp9/13/

Comment: @denislexic Your method doesn't - and shouldn't - work. I don't know where you got that syntax, but it doesn't work in plain CSS. I edited my answer to show you what the keyframes should look like alongside with an example.

Answer (score 9):

#### Tip for using transitions if it still isn't working...

Make sure you're not setting two separate transitions for different properties like this:

```css
transition: margin 1000ms ease-in-out;
transition: box-shadow 1000ms ease-in-out;
```

It's obvious what's happening when looking in your browser's debugging tools:

[image]

The `box-shadow` will animate as intended, but `margin` isn't considered due to normal css rule handling.

The correct way is to combine the rules:

```css
transition: margin 1000ms ease-in-out, box-shadow 1000ms ease-in-out;
```

Comment: This doesn't really address the OP, who isn't using any `transition` property in their code.

Comment: Fair point but kind of ironic the accepted answer tells the OP to switch transition and it becomes the accepted answer ;-)

Comment: Well, to be fair, the accepted answer says "you don't need animations, just use transitions" and then shows how to use transitions to achieve the effect. (it then goes into more detail to achieve add-on requests from OP) This answer assumes the use of transitions from the get-go and doesn't reference OP's code. It may be more worthwhile as a comment to the accepted answer, or rewritten to show how to do what OP wants via transitions *with* the additional warning of not overwriting one declaration with another.

Comment: And my eye went right to the answer - from the title alone - and tbh I didn’t notice until you said so that the actual original question didn’t mention transition. Sometimes my answers are just useful things I thought might help someone in future with the same silly mistake I just made. Sometimes I get downvoted. Sometimes I don’t. Sometimes I get offended and sometimes I don’t.

Answer (score -1):

To create animations witch CSS3 you need to:

1. Create a class with animation attribute; to work in some browsers you need to put prefixes: `-webkit-`, `-o-`, `-moz-`.
2. Create animation keyframes

see the example:

```css
.animate{
    animation: myAnimation 10s; 
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-play-state: running;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-delay: 0;
    animation-timing-function: 1;
    animation-direction: alternate;

    -webkit-animation: myAnimation 10s;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: 1;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;

    -moz-animation: myAnimation 10s;
    -moz-animation-direction: alternate;
    -moz-animation-play-state: running;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: 1;
    -moz-animation-direction: alternate;

    -o-animation: myAnimation 10s;
    -o-animation-direction: alternate;
    -o-animation-play-state: running;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -o-animation-delay: 0;
    -o-animation-timing-function: 1;
    -o-animation-direction: alternate;
}

    @keyframes myAnimation {
        0%      { margin-top: 0; margin-left: 50px}
        25%     { margin-top: 100px; margin-left: 50px }
        50%     { margin-top: 0; margin-left: 50px }
        75%     { margin-top: 100px; margin-left: 50px }
        100%    { margin-top: 0; margin-left: 50px }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes myAnimation {
        0%      { margin-top: 0; margin-left: 100px}
        25%     { margin-top: 100px; margin-left: 100px }
        50%     { margin-top: 0; margin-left: 100px }
        75%     { margin-top: 100px; margin-left: 100px }
        100%    { margin-top: 0; margin-left: 100px }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes myAnimation {
        0%      { margin-top: 0; margin-left: 100px}
        25%     { margin-top: 100px; margin-left: 100px }
        50%     { margin-top: 0; margin-left: 100px }
        75%     { margin-top: 100px; margin-left: 100px }
        100%    { margin-top: 0; margin-left: 100px }
    }
    @-o-keyframes myAnimation {
        0%      { margin-top: 0; margin-left: 100px}
        25%     { margin-top: 100px; margin-left: 100px }
        50%     { margin-top: 0; margin-left: 100px }
        75%     { margin-top: 100px; margin-left: 100px }
        100%    { margin-top: 0; margin-left: 100px }
    }
```

Comment: Not-prefixed rules should always come last. W3C spec should override browser specific rules.

Comment: This is now massively out of date. Prefixes are no longer needed.