# How to add a space between images in a CSS image slideshow?

Tags: html, css, optimization, slideshow

EDIT:

Good progress... By updating the following code, I almost get exactly what I want to achieve, *but I don't understand exactly why it almost works*. Spacing both sides during transition, spacing hidden after transition, *but* with a slight amount of clipping of image: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LWqPJB

```
body { 
     margin: -6%; 
} 
div#slider { 
     overflow: hidden; 
}
div#slider figure img { 
     width: 18%; 
     float: left; 
     padding-left: 1%; 
     padding-right: 1%;
}
```

Although, it's not a perfect solution, the second alternative that seems to do the job is:

```
div#slider {
    margin-left: -6%;
    margin-right: -6%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div#slider figure img {
    width: 18%; 
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    float: left;
}
```

---

**Problem**

I'm implementing a simple image slideshow in a webpage using only HTML and CSS. The code I am starting with is below and at https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wJRVwP

Currently each slide follows the next with no space between images (*image 1*). However, I'm trying to add a 100px space between each image that is only visible during the transition. So attempting to add a gap, I change the CSS code below;

from:

```
div#slider figure img { width: 20%; float: left;}
```

(*demo 1:* https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wJRVwP)

to:

```
div#slider figure img { width: 20%; float: left; padding-left: 100px;}
```

(*demo 2:* https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vxvoNy)

The result of changing the code adds a 100px space between all images, *but*, the code change introduces a new problem — images no longer align and progressively get worse after each slide change (*image 2*).

> **Question**
>
> How can I achieve a space between images and fix this? In code, how
>   can I change the CSS code to add a 100px space between each image, *and* keep
>   all images aligned during and after transition?

---

**Images**

1. demo 1 during transition.

[image]

2. demo 1 after transition.

[image]

3. required outcome.

[image]

---

**Code**

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wJRVwP

```css
@keyframes slidy {
  0% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  20% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  25% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  45% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  50% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  70% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  75% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  95% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -400%;
  }
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

div#slider {
  overflow: hidden;
}

div#slider figure img {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}

div#slider figure {
  position: relative;
  width: 500%;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0;
  animation: 20s slidy infinite;
}
```

```html
<base href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/">
<div id="slider">
  <figure>
    <img src="austin-fireworks.jpg" alt>
    <img src="taj-mahal_copy.jpg" alt>
    <img src="austin-fireworks.jpg" alt>
    <img src="ankor-wat.jpg" alt>
    <img src="austin-fireworks.jpg" alt>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30240181/css3-animate-margins

Answer (score 1):

apply a `box-sizing:border-box` property to all `img`. Add padding left and right (it look somewhat odd if you don't pad both sides).

These are the css adjustments

```
div#slider figure img { 
    width: 20%; 
    float: left; 
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    box-sizing:border-box
}
```

Snippet below

```css
@keyframes slidy {
  0% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  20% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  25% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  45% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  50% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  70% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  75% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  95% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -400%;
  }
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

div#slider {
  overflow: hidden;
}

div#slider figure img {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

div#slider figure {
  position: relative;
  width: 500%;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0;
  animation: 20s slidy infinite;
}
```

```html
<base href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/">
<div id="slider">
  <figure>
    <img src="austin-fireworks.jpg" alt>
    <img src="taj-mahal_copy.jpg" alt>
    <img src="austin-fireworks.jpg" alt>
    <img src="ankor-wat.jpg" alt>
    <img src="austin-fireworks.jpg" alt>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's close, but not it exactly. The 100px space between each image should only visible during the transition, the 100px space, on both sides, should disappear out of sight after the transition finishes. i.e. the 100px space moves off the visible area -- the image and 100px spacing is larger than the visible area of the slider. I'm updating the question with a new image to clarify. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
Change the CSS like below:
@keyframes slidy {
    0% { left: 0%;}
    20% { left: 0%; }
    25% { left: -100%;}
    45% { left: -100%; }
    50% { left: -200%; margin-left: 100px;}
    70% { left: -200%; }
    75% { left: -300%; }
    95% { left: -300%; }
    100% { left: -400%; margin-left: 0px;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not it either. I've updated the question with another image to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

```
<base href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/">
<div id="slider">
<figure>
<img src="austin-fireworks.jpg" alt>
<img src="taj-mahal_copy.jpg" alt>
<img src="austin-fireworks.jpg" alt>
<img src="ankor-wat.jpg" alt>
<img src="austin-fireworks.jpg" alt>
</figure>
</div>
<style>
    @keyframes slidy {
        0% { left: 0%; }
        20% { left: 0%; }
        25% { left: -100%;}
        45% { left: -100%; }
        50% { left: -200%; }
        70% { left: -200%; }
        75% { left: -300%; }
        95% { left: -300%; }
        100% { left: -400%;}
    }
    body { margin: 0; } 
    div#slider { overflow: hidden;}
    div#slider figure img { 
        width: 19%; float: left;margin-left:0.5%;margin-right:0.5%;
    }
    div#slider figure { 
      position: relative;
      width: 500%;
      margin: 0px;
      left: 0;
      text-align: left;
      font-size: 0;
      animation: 20s slidy infinite; 

    }

</style>
```

Comment: Try this code, I updated code based on your updated question.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this still shows spacing after the transition. The spacing should be cropped after transition.